# Obtener DataAnnotations del Modelo en el Controlador #c

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

una consulta, como puedo obtener las diferentes DataAnnotations agregadas en el Modelo peroe estando en Controlador, mi idea seria algo asi:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public IActionResult Create(clsTipoServicioTarifaVM VM)
  {

     string display = VM.EstadoId.DataAnnotations["Display"];
  }
```

Se Podria? o con que referencia deberia buscar informacion?

Estoy usando .Net Core 3.1

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta. Para que queres obtenerlas? Para mostrarlas en la vista? Porque si es asi no es necesario obtenerlas para mostrarlas

Comment: el data annotation lo aplicas sobre el objeto que representa al model para validarlo, lo que quieres hacer es aplicar la validacion? porque sino no entiendo cual seria el sentido de acceder a los atributos aplicados a las propiedades de la clase que representa ese model

Comment: que version de asp.net mvc estas utilizando? porque mvc solo es una cosa, ahora si es con net core es diferente, mas que nada para saber si estan corrrectamente definidas las etiqueta

Comment: necesito obtenerlas porque en la validacion edl Model State hay ocaciones que me muestra el mensaje: "The value '' is invalid.", para solucionar eso ya me hice un metodo q reemplaza ese mensaje, pero me falta obtener ese Display asignado al Model, puedo obtener el nombre del campo con el error pero me guatria obtener el Display

Answer (score 1):

Una opcion es que obtengas la Meta informacion de tu clase:

Como no agregas el nombre de tu propiedad agregue una personal para que te guies
con este ejemplo

```
     public class UserModel
        {
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            [Display(Name ="First Name")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
        }

      public string ObtenerDisplayName()
    {
          MemberInfo props= typeof(UserModel).GetProperty("FirstName") as MemberInfo;
   //si quieres obtener todas las propiedades usa GetProperties()
            var atributoDisplay= props.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;

         string display = atributoDisplay.Name;//salida: First Name

     return display;
    }
```

Comment: te cuento que en la var props siempre obtengo null, tengo q cambiar algo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el model state para validar las anotaciones que tengas en un dto 
por ejemplo:

```
public class Ejemplo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Propeidad requerida")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

ahora en el controlador puedes responder usando el dataAnotation de esta manera

```
 [HttpPost("postEjemplo")]
    public IActionResult postEjemplo([FromBody] Ejemplo ejemplo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok("");
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

ya el mensaje de error lo puedes personalizar usando las propiedades del modelstate respondiendo con la estructura de json que prefieras

Answer (score 1):

aqui esta la solucion completa que funciono para mi:

```
      public static Dictionary<int, string> getDisplay_VM(object VM)
  {
     Dictionary<int, string> dicRes = new Dictionary<int, string>();
     try
     {
        int Key = 1;

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in VM.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
           var atributoDisplay = info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute));
           if (atributoDisplay != null)
           {
              var lst = atributoDisplay.ToList();
              if (lst.Count > 0)
              {
                 DisplayAttribute item = (DisplayAttribute)lst[0];
                 dicRes.Add(Key, item.Name);
                 Key++;
              }
           }
        }

        return dicRes;

     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        return new Dictionary<int, string>();
     }
  }
```

gracias @Miguel y @excreed